# Select2 custom matcher, but keep stripDiacritics

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I know in previous versions of select2, stripDiacritics was exported so it was accessible outside of the default matcher. In the current version, 4.0.1 it seems impossible to write a custom matcher and using select2's stripDiacritics, since is not exported in `$.fn.select2.defaults`

**What's the best way I can pull the original `stripDiacritics` for me to write a custom matcher?**

I'm trying to write a matcher that matches both the option's text and a data attribute. I'm trying to avoid patching select2's source, I imagine it will be nightmare if I follow that path.

### Update

I've highlighted the actual question and posted additional details around the code I'm working with, as suggested in the comments:

I'm not asking for someone to write the new matcher (based on [`$.fn.select2.defaults.defaults.matcher`](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/4.0.1/src/js/select2/defaults.js#L309)) for me, I'm simply asking for *the best* way to pull the original [`stripDiacritics`](https://github.com/select2/select2/blob/4.0.1/src/js/select2/defaults.js#L300) which is private, so that I can use it.

I could, simply copy the function (and it's dependencies: the `DIACRITICS` object) to my code, but that's the hole I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: you did't provide your code, if you add then it is better for the viewer to understand and may be someone give the solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `stripDiacritics`s is a private method, there's not much you can do about it (other than parsing the source code).

However, if you're happy with copying only the `stripDiacritics` method from the select2 codebase and relying on select2 to provide the `DIACRITICS` dependency, you can always just require the `'select2/diacritics'` module:

```
$.fn.select2.amd.require(['select2/diacritics'], function (DIACRITICS) {
  // stripDiacritics code copied from select2
  function stripDiacritics (text) {
    // Used 'uni range + named function' from http://jsperf.com/diacritics/18
    function match(a) {
      return DIACRITICS[a] || a;
    }

    return text.replace(/[^\u0000-\u007E]/g, match);
  }

  $(".awesome").select2({
    // declare your matcher code here with access to stripDiacritics
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is closer to what I was looking? Would you consider an oversight the fact that both `DIACRITICS` and the _default matcher_ are public but `stripDiacritics` is not an oversight/something that should be fixed?? I don't know how familiar you are with _select2_, I'm asking this more from a JavaScript developer perspective?

Comment: Select2's codebase changed a lot between 3.5.4 and 4.0.0. I searched the commit messages for something like "making stripDiacritics private because X" but haven't found anything. Therefore I think it was a mistake.  You can always start a discussion by opening an issue in [their repository](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues) If it bothers you.

Comment: Thanks @jannis, I will! I wasn't sure, as Javascript isn't my stronger, but I will follow my gut and your advice and start a discussion there. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Leito, did you manage eventually? I am using v 4.0.6 and whenever I use this code my custom matcher is disregarded...